# Is it possible to integrate jetpay merchant services in MAGENTO

Tags: php

Is it possible to integrate jetpay merchant services in MAGENTO

If yes, HOW?

If No, WHY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to integrate jetpay merchant services in MAGENTO. Because jetpay didn't provide any API regarding it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to integrate merchant services between Jetpay and Magento through Trexle https://trexle.com/integrations/jetpay/magento. For the record, Jetpay does have an API https://stage.collectorsolutions.com/magic-api/swagger/ui/index but no direct integration with Magento.

Comment: Add the relevant content from your link to the body of your answer.

Comment: I am not sure what contents you are asking me to add. The first link is an installation instructions page and the second is the official jetway API documentation link grabbed from their site.